# Telephone Automated by Dfa

Tags: automation, finite-automata, deterministic

Some organizations have automated their telephone system so that messages can be sent via pushing the buttons on the telephone. The buttons are labeled with both numerals and letters as shown:

Notice that certain letters are omitted, presumably for historical reasons. However, it is common to use * to represent letter q and # to represent letter z. Common schemes do not use a one-to-one encoding of each letter. However, if we wanted such an encoding, one method would be to use two digits for each letter: The first digit is the key containing the letter. The second digit is the index, 1, 2, or 3, of the letter on the key. For example, to send the word "cat", we'd punch: 2 3 2 1 8 1 c a t An exception would be made for 'q' and 'z', as the only letters on the keys '*' and '#' respectively. Give the dfa for communicating a series of any of the twenty-six letters, where the input alphabet is the set of digits {1, ...., 9, *, #} and the output alphabet is the set of available letters. Note that outputs occur only every other input. So we need a convention for what output will be shown in the transducer in case there is no output. Use λ for this output.

Comment: I could not find the question..